# PHP/MySQL: Getting form information, not working as planned

Tags: php, mysql, forms

```
 <?php
$ip = htmlspecialchars($_GET["ip"]);
$serverIp = "a";
$a = "a";
include("mysql.php"); 
$votes = "serverVotes";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE serverIp = $_POST[serverIp] ORDER BY $votes DESC");

  if($row['serverIp'] = $_POST[serverIp]) {
        echo 'Yes1.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST[serverIp]) {
        echo 'No1.'; //debugging
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

  if($row['serverIp'] = $_POST[serverIp]) {
        echo 'Yes2.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST[serverIp]) {
        echo 'No2.'; //debugging
}

    }
?>
```

I'm trying to make it, so that if "serverIp" exists in the database, it will echo certain information, and if it doesn't exists, it will just do nothing.  I don't think it is 
actually getting the IP from the form, but I may be wrong, it may be some other problem.

Comment: Not sure what your $_GET['ip'] is all about, but you know you can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for the client IP?

Comment: please post the result of var_dump($_POST['serverip'])

Comment: You should definitely not use htmlspecialchars to escape mysql query, at very least try mysql_real_escape_string. You should also enclose $_POST[serverIp] in mysql query with single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
$ip = htmlspecialchars($_GET["ip"]);
$serverIp = "a";
$a = "a";
include("mysql.php"); 
$votes = "serverVotes";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE serverIp = '".$_POST['serverIp']."' ORDER BY $votes DESC");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

  if($row['serverIp'] === $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'Yes1.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'No1.'; //debugging
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

  if($row['serverIp'] === $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'Yes2.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'No2.'; //debugging
}

    }
```

Comment: what did you change specifically? this isn't very useful unless you point out what you did to help...

Comment: this misses mysql_fetch_array

Comment: @ScottM. can't you see what's the difference between the codes? I added single quotes to $_POST['serverIp'] and changed "=" to "===" and in mysql query I changed "serverIp = $_POST[serverIp]"... please read both codes before you post such comment... thank you :)

Comment: @RobinVanPersi i know, but it's hard to miss things like that sometimes, especially for a frustrated programmer coming into StackOverflow after working on a problem for awhile. Just a suggestion. Your answer looks good though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the IP if using it from `$_POST` and enclose it in quotes.. Rather than `htmlspecialchars()`, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape input to a SQL query:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE serverIp = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['serverIp'] . "' ORDER BY $votes DESC");
```

Following that, you need to actually fetch a row before `$row` will have any value.  In a couple of places, you've mistakenly also used the assignment operator `=` when you intended to use the equality operator `==`:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
// Now do stuff with $row:
//  All of these should use == for equality, not = for assignment
// Also, enclose array keys in quotes inside $_POST['serverIp]. Though it may work
// without the quotes, it is bad practice to omit them, and will fill your error logs
// with warnings.
if($row['serverIp'] == $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'Yes1.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'No1.'; //debugging
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

  if($row['serverIp'] == $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'Yes2.'; //debugging
}
  if($row['serverIp'] != $_POST['serverIp']) {
        echo 'No2.'; //debugging
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you hit the first `if` statement, you haven't yet assigned anything to `$row`. try removing the first `if` statement and getting into the `while` loop before accessing `$row`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what your problem is, but anyways, this is wrong:

```
if($row['serverIp'] = $_POST[serverIp]) {
```

This sets $row['serverIp'] to $_POST[serverIp], and than checks if it's true. You might want

```
if($row['serverIp'] == $_POST[serverIp]) {
```

instead.

Also, `$_POST[serverIp]` is wrong, this will look for the constant 'serverIp' (whick probably doesn't exist). It will work though, because PHP makes it a string, but you will get PHP-notices from it.

Also, your MySQL query is not secure. Someone could do some nasty things with it by using MySQL-Injections.

And,

```
  if($row['serverIp'] = $_POST[serverIp]) {
        echo 'Yes2.'; //debugging
  }
```

You don't need that if statement, since you already put `WHERE` in your MySQL query. So it will always be true.

Comment: How can I make this code more secure?  Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Hunt3r Google 'MySQL Injection' and you will find loads of information about it and how to prevent it :)